# MS SQL 2008 Studio creating syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a project where I create a query string dynamically. It's not too complicated, just complex.  I specifically have a problem adding a select into the mix.  Studio adds an "as" when I save the view.

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Users.ID AS UserId, dbo.Users_Info.Home_Area_Code, dbo.Users_Info.Work_Area_Code, dbo.Users_Info.State AS HomeState, 
                      (CASE WHEN (dbo.Users_Info.Address1 = '' OR
                      dbo.Users_Info.Address1 IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS has_home_address, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.ID NOT IN
                          (SELECT     UserID
                            FROM          Users_Client_Companies) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Eliminate_TSI_Clients, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.ID IN
                          (SELECT     individual_number
                            FROM          qUsersPresented_ES) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Presented_ES, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.ID IN
                          (SELECT     individual_number
                            FROM          qUsersPlaced_ES
                            WHERE      isnull(date_of_placement, '') > '') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Placed_ES, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.ID IN
                          (SELECT     individual_number
                            FROM          qUsersPresented_CS) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Presented_CS, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.ID IN
                          (SELECT     individual_number
                            FROM          qUsersPlaced_CS
                            WHERE      isnull(date_of_placement, '') > '') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Placed_CS, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.ID IN
                          (SELECT     individual_number
                            FROM          QEliteAdCandidatesPanel
                            WHERE      isnull(date_of_placement, '') > '') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Placed_EJA, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.ID IN
                          (SELECT     individual_number
                            FROM          QEliteAdCandidatesPanel) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Presented_EJA, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.id IN
                          (SELECT     ID
                            FROM          qUsers_TTMember) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TT_Member, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.id IN
                          (SELECT     ID
                            FROM          qUsers_HasHomeEmail) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Has_Home_Email, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.id IN
                          (SELECT     ID
                            FROM          qUsers_HasWorkEmail) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Has_Work_Email, dbo.Companies.Sales_Level, dbo.Users_Salary.ISIPCT AS Individual_Letter_Per, 
                      dbo.Users_Salary.ISCPCT AS Corporate_Letter_Per, (CASE WHEN (dbo.Users_Info.Basic_JobAd = 1 OR
                      dbo.Users_Info.Custom_JobAd = 1 OR
                      dbo.Users_Info.Elite_JobAd = 1 OR
                      dbo.Users_Info.EJA_Candidate = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS job_board, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                          (SELECT     company_id
                            FROM          Companies_Adv) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_Adv, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                          (SELECT     company_id
                            FROM          Companies_BJA) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_BJA, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                          (SELECT     company_id
                            FROM          Companies_CJA) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_CJA, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                          (SELECT     company_id
                            FROM          Companies_CS) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_CS, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                          (SELECT     company_id
                            FROM          Companies_EJA) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_EJA, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                          (SELECT     company_id
                            FROM          Companies_ES) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_ES, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                          (SELECT     company_id
                            FROM          Companies_Intern) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_Intern, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                          (SELECT     company_id
                            FROM          Companies_OrgAssess) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_OrgAssess, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                          (SELECT     company_id
                            FROM          Companies_SB) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_SB,
                          (SELECT     MAX(date_purchased) AS EJA_Date_Purchased
                            FROM          dbo.QEliteContacts
                            WHERE      (contact_id = dbo.Users.ID)) AS Date_Purchased_EJA, 
                          dbo.Users_Salary.ISTEC1 AS Technical_Federal_Per,
                          dbo.Users_Salary.ISTEC2 AS Technical_StateLocal_Per,
```

The view QEliteContacts is as follows:

```
SELECT     bd.date_purchased, bd.ID, csc.contact_id
FROM         dbo.Board_Details AS bd LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Client_Services_Contacts AS csc ON csc.service_id = bd.ID
WHERE     (bd.ad_type LIKE '%Elite%')
```

Near the bottom of the first block of code is the statement "(SELECT     MAX(date_purchased) AS EJA_Date_Purchased".  This is the new code I have added to the view. I get and error "invalid syntax near 'as'".  If I remove the alias from the max(date_purchased) studio will add 'as expr1' when I save the view. If I remove the alias from the select, studio will add 'as expr1' when I save the view.

To tell the truth, I'm not sure I'm attacking the problem of getting the max date properly.

Comment: probably you already have `EJA_Date_Purchased` in `dbo.Users_Info` table

Comment: Nope.  I'm creating that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the second 'as'.ie, remove the portion ' AS Date_Purchased_EJA ' and give that instead of ' AS EJA_Date_Purchased '.In effect there should be only the first 'AS' statement.Then execute the query in Query Designer window and not in View Designer Window.The code is shown below.

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Users.ID AS UserId, dbo.Users_Info.Home_Area_Code, dbo.Users_Info.Work_Area_Code, dbo.Users_Info.State AS HomeState, 
                          (CASE WHEN (dbo.Users_Info.Address1 = '' OR
                          dbo.Users_Info.Address1 IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS has_home_address, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.ID NOT IN
                              (SELECT     UserID
                                FROM          Users_Client_Companies) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Eliminate_TSI_Clients, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.ID IN
                              (SELECT     individual_number
                                FROM          qUsersPresented_ES) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Presented_ES, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.ID IN
                              (SELECT     individual_number
                                FROM          qUsersPlaced_ES
                                WHERE      isnull(date_of_placement, '') > '') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Placed_ES, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.ID IN
                              (SELECT     individual_number
                                FROM          qUsersPresented_CS) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Presented_CS, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.ID IN
                              (SELECT     individual_number
                                FROM          qUsersPlaced_CS
                                WHERE      isnull(date_of_placement, '') > '') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Placed_CS, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.ID IN
                              (SELECT     individual_number
                                FROM          QEliteAdCandidatesPanel
                                WHERE      isnull(date_of_placement, '') > '') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Placed_EJA, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.ID IN
                              (SELECT     individual_number
                                FROM          QEliteAdCandidatesPanel) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Presented_EJA, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.id IN
                              (SELECT     ID
                                FROM          qUsers_TTMember) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TT_Member, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.id IN
                              (SELECT     ID
                                FROM          qUsers_HasHomeEmail) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Has_Home_Email, (CASE WHEN dbo.users.id IN
                              (SELECT     ID
                                FROM          qUsers_HasWorkEmail) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Has_Work_Email, dbo.Companies.Sales_Level, dbo.Users_Salary.ISIPCT AS Individual_Letter_Per, 
                          dbo.Users_Salary.ISCPCT AS Corporate_Letter_Per, (CASE WHEN (dbo.Users_Info.Basic_JobAd = 1 OR
                          dbo.Users_Info.Custom_JobAd = 1 OR
                          dbo.Users_Info.Elite_JobAd = 1 OR
                          dbo.Users_Info.EJA_Candidate = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS job_board, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                              (SELECT     company_id
                                FROM          Companies_Adv) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_Adv, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                              (SELECT     company_id
                                FROM          Companies_BJA) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_BJA, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                              (SELECT     company_id
                                FROM          Companies_CJA) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_CJA, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                              (SELECT     company_id
                                FROM          Companies_CS) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_CS, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                              (SELECT     company_id
                                FROM          Companies_EJA) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_EJA, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                              (SELECT     company_id
                                FROM          Companies_ES) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_ES, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                              (SELECT     company_id
                                FROM          Companies_Intern) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_Intern, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                              (SELECT     company_id
                                FROM          Companies_OrgAssess) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_OrgAssess, (CASE WHEN dbo.Users_Info.Current_Company_Number IN
                              (SELECT     company_id
                                FROM          Companies_SB) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Comp_SB,
                              (SELECT MAX([EJA_Date_Purchased]) from
                               (SELECT date_purchased AS [EJA_Date_Purchased]
                                FROM          dbo.QEliteContacts
                                WHERE      (contact_id = dbo.Users.ID))t), 
                              dbo.Users_Salary.ISTEC1 AS Technical_Federal_Per,
                              dbo.Users_Salary.ISTEC2 AS Technical_StateLocal_Per,
```

Comment: (SELECT     MAX(date_purchased) AS Expr1
   FROM          dbo.QEliteContacts
   WHERE      (contact_id = dbo.Users.ID)) AS Date_Purchased_EJA,

That's what I get when I execute plus the error "invalid column Date_Purchased_EJA.

Comment: are you trying to create the view using view designer window???if you are trying to create the view in query designer window this will not happen.

Comment: It's an existing view and I'm trying to add the select.  I right click and click on design.

Comment: instead try using ALTER VIEW statement in Query Designer Window.Using the View Designer window always create this extra AS statement for aggregate functions.

Comment: So, to edit a view, you recommend right click, script view as, alter to, new query editor window?

Comment: (SELECT     MAX(date_purchased)  AS Date_Purchased_EJA
                            FROM          dbo.QEliteContacts
                            WHERE      (contact_id = dbo.Users.ID)),

I get the following errors;
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure View_CallListFields, Line 125
Invalid column name 'Date_Purchased_EJA'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure View_CallListFields, Line 126
Invalid column name 'Date_Purchased_EJA'.

The where clause is;
WHERE (Contact_Type_Acronym = 'ha') AND (Date_Purchased_EJA >= '2013/01/01') AND (Date_Purchased_EJA <= '2013/10/08')

Comment: I have edited my code.Give the WHERE condition like (SELECT MAX([EJA_Date_Purchased]) from
        (SELECT date_purchased AS [EJA_Date_Purchased]
                                FROM          dbo.QEliteContacts
                                WHERE      (contact_id = dbo.Users.ID))t) >= '2013/01/01'

Comment: The ColdFusion html code that call the query is:

<cfquery datasource="#request.dsn#" name="BuildCallList" >    #preservesinglequotes(request.qryString)#)
</cfquery>

The variable qryString is;
 select distinct(cl.userid) from View_CallListFields as cl where 0 = 0 AND ( 1=1 and ( ( cl.Contact_Type_Acronym = 'ha' ) ) and ( cl.Date_Purchased_EJA >= '2013/01/01' AND cl.Date_Purchased_EJA <= '2013/10/08' ) )

View_CallListFields is the view we are working on and doesn't have a where clause.  I only added the where clause from above to test execute it.